# EKS Latency Issue

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, latency

I have upgraded my EKS from version 1.19 to 1.21 and now i am facing latency issue to my applications. This issue was not there before upgrade, i have checked all k8s components but still see the latency. Can any buddy suggest, what steps i can do to resolve this issue.

[image]

I have verified all the k8s componetns, also there is no restart of any pods.

Comment: Where is the latency being measured? What is this graph from?

Comment: It's from AWS and also user confirmed

Comment: "From AWS" where? What latency are you measuring?

Comment: ELB Latency, actually i am using ELB monitor option to major it

Comment: did you upgrade the cluster addons component match with your eks version?

Comment: Yes, I have done that.

Comment: This issue has been resolved, as my services in k8s need more CPU limits to work in the new eks version. I have increased the CPU limits for services and also added one more node to add pods to that. This issue happen due to pod have horizontal scaling and not getting proper resources in high pick of traffic